# How to distinguish an array from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to distinguish an array from an array of arrays or array of objects in jQuery?

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var a2 = [[12,'Smith',1],[13,'Jones',2]];
var a3 = [{val:'12', des:'Smith', num:1}];

//a = array
//a2 and a3 = multidimensional array
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Also note that this has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use:

```
$.isArray(a[0]);
```

Here's the documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/

This is definitely not the only way to find out. You could do this in pure JS too, using:

```
Array.isArray(v[0]);
```

Comment: `Array.isArray` for pure JS

Comment: `$.isArray === Array.isArray`, they're the same thing, err

Comment: @vic3685 - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Very raw way of checking:

```
function isMultiDimensional(array) {
  return array.some(element => Array.isArray(element))
}
```

This basically checks if any of your elements is also an array

If you consider multidimensional arrays where all elements are arrays, look at the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This function can solve your problem

```
 function checkArray(arr){
      if(!Array.isArray(arr[0])) return 'simple array';
      else  return 'Not simple array [Array of arrays (or) Array of objects]';
 }

 checkArray(a);    // simple array
 checkArray(a1);    // Not simple array [Array of arrays (or) Array of objects]
```

Comment: I (respectfully) disagree with this; an array of arrays is, for all practical purposes, a multidimensional array. The fact language itself doesn't have a specific concept of multidimensional arrays is mere technicality.

Comment: Ya.. So do u mean that array of arrays is a multi dimensional array ?

Comment: Not neccessarily, but "array of arrays" is the closest thing a weakly-typed language can have to a multidimensional array. This is why I feel that saying *is not supported by JavaScript* is not correct.